# Running an executable in a child directory from parent directory windows

Tags: python, windows, executable

I have the current file structure in a folder with nothing else in it:

- (folder) crypt
- (file) run.bat

I'm on Windows and I'm trying to execute a python.exe with run.bat that is in the crypt folder. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I just had to add a "./crypt/python.exe" argument as the thing to run.